# Calculating average of cells if a condition is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset that gives the price of a security for each month for 12 years:

```
Month: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1 2 3 4 .....
Year:  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1   1  1 2 2 2 2
Price: x x x x x x x x x x   x  x x x x x
```

I want to write a formula such that the average price for each quarter of the security is calculated and stored in the following table:

```
Quarter: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
Year:    1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
Price:   y y y y y y y y
```

The list goes on to 40 years

What would be the simplest way of doing so without creating any additional cells?
I currently use an averageifs formula, but not sure if that is the most efficient way of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, the simplest and easy way without trying to get complicated formulas, would be transposing your data, and then Pivot Table:

**TRANSPOSING:** You can do this with a formula if you have Excel 2019 or higher`=TRANSPOSE(A1:Y3)`. If not, you can copy/paste transposing:

[image]

> **[FUNCTION TRANSPOSE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/transpose-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027)**

**PIVOT TABLE:** Your easiest shot is Pivot Table. Just set it up like this:

1. *Year field*  in columns section
2. *Month Field* in rows section
3. *Price field* into values section and **make sure yous et it up to calculate average instead of count or sum up**
4. Group *Month Field* in groups of 3, to make quarters.

[image]